# Meteor (0.9.0.1): Issue assigning admin role using a roles package

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using this [roles meteor package](http://atmospherejs.com/digilord/roles) and I can't get to my admin panel.

The behaviour I've got at the moment is logged in admin user gets redirected to home page instead of being shown the admin area.

If I run the following code I get returned "false" suggesting that the user is not an admin user:

```
Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin']);
```

If I try adding the roles on the console I get this:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles("Nvu2wZRg3K2wd4j4u", ['admin']);
```

undefined

```
insert failed: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.roles.$name_1  dup key: { : "admin" }


update failed: Access denied

Roles.addUsersToRoles("Meteor.user()", ['admin']);
undefined

insert failed: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.roles.$name_1  dup key: { : "admin" }
```

This seems to suggest that this user already has the role assigned to it.  The permission error I expect is down to the roles not being published.  If there's a duplicate error then it seems like this user should have the admin role assigned to it.

Here's the relevant code.
Templates:

```
<template name="adminTemplate">
{{#if isAdminUser}}
    {{> accountsAdmin}}
{{else}}
    Must be admin to see this...
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="accountsAdmin">
 accountsAdmin template
</template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.adminTemplate.helpers({
  // check if user is an admin
  isAdminUser: function() {
      return Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin']);
  }
})
```

my router.js file

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});


Router.map( function () {
 this.route('home', {path: '/'});
 this.route('about', {path: '/about'});
 this.route('faq', {path: '/faq'});
 this.route('myaccount', {path: '/myaccount'});

 this.route('admin', {
    layoutTemplate: 'adminlayout',
    path:'/admin',
    template: 'accountsAdmin',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        } else if(!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
            console.log('redirecting');
            this.redirect('/');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

I've got the following in my startup.js

```
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // This is temporary
    if (Meteor.users.findOne("Nvu2wZRg3K2wd4j4u"))
        Roles.addUsersToRoles("Nvu2wZRg3K2wd4j4u", ['admin']);
  });
```

Any one got any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the user role in the client is not possible, you should do this stuff server side, and hard-coding UUID in code is never a good idea (even temporary).

For testing purpose, you can use this code :

`server/collections/users.js` :

```
insertUsers=function(){
  var adminId=Accounts.createUser({
    username:"admin",
    password:"password"
  });
  //
  Roles.addUsersToRoles(adminId,"admin");
};
```

`server/startup.js` :

```
// always start from scratch (you will want to comment this line at some point !)
Meteor.users.remove({});
if(Meteor.users.find().count()===0){
  insertUsers();
}
```

You can get rid of your `isAdminUser` helper, Roles provides a helper specifically designed for this purpose, it's called `{{isInRole "list of comma separated roles"}}`

```
{{#if isInRole "admin"}}
  ...
{{else}}
```

Of course you have to be logged in because the helper is testing against `Meteor.user()`.

I guess your admin user never got the chance of being affected the admin role...

The rest of your code looks OK so hopefully it should work after addressing these details.

Comment: That's perfect thank you :)  I only had to change "username" to "email" in the insertUsers function.  Got it working now :)